# Changing the "x" in background-position: "x"px "y"px using jQuery/Javascript for a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, sprite

I've just started using sprites to cut down HTTP requests and I'm having a little bit of a problem converting my old script for dealing with my hover animations into the new system. I don't really want to be having a separate function for each button as that is painful especially with the amount of buttons, even copy and paste would be a pain. I don't believe it's the most efficient way of doing things either, not by a long shot and efficiency is the aim here.

I have gotten this far with it:

```
$(".socButton").hover(function(){
        var iD = $(this).attr("id");

        var pos = $("#" + iD).css("background-position");

        var splitPos = pos.split("px");

        splitPos[0] = parseInt(splitPos[0]) += 24;

        newPos = splitPos.join("px");

        alert(newPos);

}, function(){

});
```

but the newPos variable just isn't alerting. I've tried some easier looking methods of just changing "background-position-x" but no dice there.

I'm not certain I need to identify the id of the element in order to change it, but it is the id which has the background-position in the stylesheet, not the class, so I'm not really certain.

Any guidance greatly appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I feel I should also point out, it was alerting fine before I added the parseInt, but some whacky results were coming about before I added it.

Comment: what do you want to add further ? you just alert the newPos and thats it ?

Comment: at this point I'm just trying to alert it so I can see if it's working but ultimately I will be changing the "background-position" to newPos

Comment: You may find [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-position&preval=50%25%2050%25) helpful

Comment: Answers below, but the += with the parseInt is what caused you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need the ID of the element. jQuery applies inline styles.

Anyway, it would probably be easier if you had a second rule for `.socButton` in your CSS, i.e. `.socButton.hover`, which would have correct background position for hover state. In jQuery you would only have to toggle the `hover` class with `$(this).toggleClass('hover')`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rn6f4/

```
$(".socButton").hover(function() {
    var pos = $(this).css("background-position");

    var splitPos = pos.split("px");

    splitPos[0] = parseInt(splitPos[0]);
    splitPos[0] += 24.0;

    newPos = splitPos.join("px");

    alert(newPos);
    $(this).css({"background-position": newPos});

}, function(){

});
```

Comment: That works great, excellent.

Not sure about your suggestion though, I don't know how you would be able to do that with sprites, without having to do a separate (albeit shorter) script for each and every button.